# Error Rendering View - JSF + CDI + Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, cdi

Boa noite, tenho o seguinte contexto:
Minha aplicacao utiliza JSF2, CDI e PrimeFaces, minha view esta rendenizando normalmente, porem, caso eu venha a acionar um F5 repetidas vezes acaba me retornando o erro de Rendering View com NullPointerException, minha view esta anotada com @ViewScoped caso eu mude para @Request o problema acaba.

> com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy
>   handleRenderException GRAVE: Error Rendering
>   View[/pages/restrito/admin/teste.xhtml] java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeContextManager.destroyBeans(ViewScopeContextManager.java:171)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeContextManager.clear(ViewScopeContextManager.java:122)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeManager.removeEldestViewMap(ViewScopeManager.java:399)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeManager.processPostConstructViewMap(ViewScopeManager.java:298)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeManager.processEvent(ViewScopeManager.java:244)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeEventListener.processEvent(ViewScopeEventListener.java:68)
>   at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
>   at
>   javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.processListener(ComponentSystemEvent.java:118)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2142)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
>   at
>   javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:739)
>   at
>   javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:739)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.getViewMap(UIViewRoot.java:1557)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeContextManager.createBean(ViewScopeContextManager.java:148)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeContext.get(ViewScopeContext.java:137)
>   at
>   org.jboss.weld.context.PassivatingContextWrapper$AbstractPassivatingContextWrapper.get(PassivatingContextWrapper.java:76)
>   at
>   org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:744)
>   at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:107)
>   at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:90)
>   at
>   org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.util.ForwardingELResolver.getValue(ForwardingELResolver.java:49)
>   at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:62)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>   at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:94)
>   at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137) at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstEqual.getValue(AstEqual.java:37) at
>   org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
>   at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>   at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:457)
>   at
>   org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeGridBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:219)
>   at
>   org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeGridLayout(PanelGridRenderer.java:90)
>   at
>   org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:40)
>   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:114)
>   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
>   at
>   org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:85)
>   at
>   org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
>   at
>   org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(OutputPanelRenderer.java:65)
>   at
>   org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanelRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputPanelRenderer.java:41)
>   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
>   at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176) at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
>   at
>   org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:85)
>   at
>   org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
>   at
>   org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206)
>   at
>   org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:123)
>   at
>   org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
>   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
>   at
>   javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
>   at
>   org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.RewriteViewHandler.renderView(RewriteViewHandler.java:196)
>   at
>   javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
>   org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:226)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TesteController implements Serializable {

/**
*
*/
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Vendedor vendedor;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
getVendedor();
}

public Vendedor getVendedor() {
if(vendedor == null)
vendedor = new Vendedor();
return vendedor;
}

public void setVendedor(Vendedor vendedor) {
this.vendedor = vendedor;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

eu estava com o mesmo problema! 
Bem provável que esteja usando um ViewScoped do CDI ( javax.faces.view.ViewScoped ) no meu caso eu estava e o problema surgiu devido eu não ter colocado o CDI para fazer os gerenciamentos nos Beans. Resolvi fazendo o seguinte passo:

Solução: Configurar o seguinte gerenciador de Beans no Web.xml (caso não tenha já feito isso):

> ```
> <resource-env-ref>
>     <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
>     <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
> </resource-env-ref>
> ```

Colocar no arquivo context.xml  o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <Context>
        <Manager pathname=""/>
       <Resource name="BeanManager" auth="Container" 
          type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager" 
          factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory"/>
      </Context>
```